# Data Validation that check 4 fields, but depending on results in 3 of them it is different with last field

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a field, where I only want to allow something in that field, if 3 other fields value is 10 or higher, if they are that, then I can enter in that field.

Then at same time if 1 of these 3 fields value is lower than 10 but higher than 0. then i have a 4th field that need to be a comment in, with reason to the low number. IF there is a comment then I can enter x in the first field, that was locked before that.

Here is a screenshot of some of it:

[image: screenshot]

Hope that can give an idea with what I want.

I have been trying with some "and" and "or" inside each other, but I'm having a hard time doing the syntax.

Comment: Can you identify the fields? your screen capture is not very useful otherwise. It woudl also be useful to have captures of the various sceniarios

Comment: A1=field where enter X to check.  
B1=Comment field, can't be empty if problem with 3 other fields.  
C1=Gives red error if higher than 0, but lower than 10.  
D1=Same red error as C1.  
E1=Same red error as C1.  
  
So if C,D or E got red error, then there must be a comment in B before I can enter something in A field. But if no error in any of them, then B field can be empty.  

Is that enough information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out of it now. After making myself blind looking at it, I tried to split it up with all checks, and then combine it to one in the end.

The result was this

```
OR(AND(OR(AND(BB12<10;BB12>0);AND(BC12<10;BC12>0);AND(BD12<10;BD12>0));AY12<>"");AND(BB12>=10;BC12>=10;BD12>=10))
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Kudos for solving your problem.  In another day (2 days after posting the question), you can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That will help other users by identifying that the problem has been solved and that there is a proven solution here.